# Can I use same branch subdomain for my iOS and Web application?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I have iOS and `Web application` using `branch.io` deeplinking.I would like to know whether I can use same subdomain for both the applications.
eg: `testdomain.app.link` for both `iOS` and `Web app`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here:

Absolutely. For your iOS app, you would use the standard [iOS SDK](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/ios/). For the web application, we have a [web SDK](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking). If you use the same Branch key for both, the links will work everywhere.

Comment: I would like to get the domain address as same.If I have used `testdomain.app.link` for iOS , I would like to know whether I could use the same for web as well.When I tried earlier it says `"domain is already in use"`

Comment: You should use the same Branch app configuration for both iOS and web. Don't try to register a second Branch app